# Hydrologic analysis with sextante-saga in qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga

I want to do hydrologic analysis of a DEM with sextante-saga in qgis. I found the plugin and the needed algorithms in SAGA, enabled them in the sextante toolbox, but when I run them, they error out saying SAGA is not installed (not where sextante is looking for them).

Where I find these SAGA binaries?

Answer (score 3):

SAGA binaries for Windows Systems:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA-2.0/SAGA2.0.8/saga_2.0.8_win32_setup.exe/download
Both versions (32 and 64 bits) work correctly, the only way in which the program is installed it will be different.
In the SEXTANTE toolbox you need to configure the path where you installed the SAGA.
More information about SAGA can be found at site: http://www.saga-gis.org
- You need install SAGA GIS before intalling QGIS, this procedure is highly recommended.